# Imagem desproporcional em resolução maior, quero ajuda pra criar uma forma de fazer que em cada resolução fique proporcional

Tags: javascript, html, css

Bom eu estou desenvolvendo um projeto muito simples mais como não tenho conhecimento das palavras chaves eu tenho dificuldades com problemas muito simples.... eu estou fazendo um player de mp3 cuja imagem esta se **esticando em resoluções**... e eu sei que isso é pra acontecer mais eu quero que a imagem em resoluções maiores **fique estática no centro pra não perder a qualidade** e não cortar partes dela...

> eu ainda não sou um "programador" então aceito dicas de como posso
> otimizar e aprimorar meu projeto

***link do repositorio*** = https://github.com/Luiz-insert/Playermp3

***link do projeto*** = https://youthful-bhabha-51291f.netlify.app/

---

**Códigos abaixo pra quem não abriu o repositorio**

> código index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>SoundTrack</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="player">
      <h4><i class="material-icons">blur_on</i> SafeZØNE</h4>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image"></div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <h5>Title</h5>
          <p class="artist">Artist</p>
          <audio controls></audio>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

> código style.css

```
@import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-icons/3.0.1/iconfont/material-icons.min.css";
@import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css";

body {
height: 100vh;
background-color: rgb(37, 35, 35);
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

#player {
background-color: rgb(214, 200, 213);
width: 90%;
max-width: 375;
box-shadow:rgb(83, 18, 126) 0px 0px 25px 7px  ;
}

.card{
box-shadow:0;
margin:0;
}

h4 {
color: rgb(83, 18, 126);
font-size: 20pt;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 0;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
padding: 10px;  
}

.card-image {

background:url("https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e02e08bd6e8f24653f315c23520") no-repeat center center /cover;
height:200px ;
padding: 10px;
flex: auto;
align-self: flex-start;
}
audio {

margin-top: 10px;
width: 100%;


}
```

> código index.js

```
const cover = document.querySelector(".card-image");
const title = document.querySelector(".card-content h5");
const artist = document.querySelector(".artist");
const audio = document.querySelector("audio");

const data = { 

  title: "Мама спалила",
  artist: "Tenderlybae",
  cover: "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e02e08bd6e8f24653f315c23520",
  file: "x3.mp3",
}

cover.style.background = `url('${data.cover}') no-repeat center center / cover`;
title.innerText = data.title;
artist.innerText = data.artist;
audio.src = data.file;
```

> código data.js

```
window.audios = [
  {
    title:
      "Musica 01",
    artist: "Artista",
    cover: "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e02e08bd6e8f24653f315c23520",
    file: "x3.mp3"
  }
  
]
```

> Imagem do qual estou me referindo  e utilizando     https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e02e08bd6e8f24653f315c23520

Answer (score 0):

O ideal seria você pegar a resolução da tela do usuário e ajustar ao tamanho ideal para cada tela, você pode pegar em javascript, mas vou dar um exemplo em css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 770px) {
 img{
    width:''; //largura em pixel ou porcentagem
    height:''; //largura em pixel
}
}
```

O que estou dizendo ao css no códico acima é **"Se a tela tiver no máximo 770px use este tamanho de imagem"**,
Porém tem muitos tamanhos de tela diferente e por isso é bom você pegar a dimensão da tela em javascript e manipular o tamanho o o javascript também, pois em css se tornaria cansativo você ter que fazer várias configurações desse tipo para vários tamanhos de dela diferente para deixar o site responsivo. Só usei esse exemplo em css por que também é válido, agora em javascript seria bom você criar uma função para fazer isto :)

Comment: é a minha primeira vez usando o stack overflow então descupa ae se eu coloquei conteudo de mais pra uma resposta simples...

Comment: mais obg pelas dicas

Comment: Não relaxa kkk, uma pergunta tem que ser como essa, clara!! Até que tá boa pra um usuário novo :)